# Push menu toggle button

Tags: javascript, html

I'm not very experienced with JavaScript, so now I'd love some help.
I'm using a push menu that slides in from the left on a website. Right now the JS code uses one button to open the menu (onclick="openNav()") and another one to close it (onclick="closeNav()").

I want to use a toggle (hamburger) button instead, to open and close, but unfortunately I can't figure out how to tweak the JS code - keeping the opacity change and the slide/push function.

Help?

JS:

```
function openNav() {
   document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "150px";
   document.getElementById("main2").style.marginLeft = "150px";
   document.body.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)";
}


function closeNav() {
   document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
   document.getElementById(”content”).style.marginLeft= "0";
   document.body.style.backgroundColor = "white";
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">CLOSE</a>
  <a href=”#anchor01”>Anchor 01</a>
  <a href=”#anchor02”>Anchor 02</a>
</div>

<div id=”content”>
<div id="main">
<span style="font-size:20px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776;</span>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like this

```
function openNav() {
   document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "150px";
   document.getElementById("main2").style.marginLeft = "150px";
   document.body.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)";
}


function closeNav() {
   document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
   document.getElementById(”content”).style.marginLeft= "0";
   document.body.style.backgroundColor = "white";
}

var clickCount = 0;

$('#togglebutton').click(function(){ //replace the id with the toggle button id
     if(clickCount%2==0){
         openNav();
     }else{
         closeNav();
     }
     clickCount++;
});
```

Here, I use a counter that increments on each click. If the counter is odd, it should be opened, otherwise, closed.

Comment: Thank you! Works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#toggle").click(function() {
    $("#mySidenav").toggleClass("active");
  if($("#mySidenav").hasClass("active")) {
    $("mySidenav").css("width","150px");
    $("main2").css("margin-left", "150px");
    $("body").css("background-color","rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)");
  }
  else {
    $("mySidenav").css("width","0px");
    $("main2").css("margin-left", "0px");
    $("body").css("background-color","white");

  }
 })
})
```

HTML :

```
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
   <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">CLOSE</a>
   <a href=”#anchor01”>Anchor 01</a>
   <a href=”#anchor02”>Anchor 02</a>
</div>

<div id=”content”>
   <div id="main">
     <span style="font-size:20px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776;</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="toggle">Toggle</div>
```